# mbtiles to geojson or geotiff

Tags: geojson, mbtiles, rasterization

I have a remote sensing data in geotiff (input_data_rs.tif) format. I want to get corresponding ground truth from open source map (e.g. roads). I was able to download the mbtiles for the country. Is there a way to convert mbtiles to geotiff or geoJson (roads.geoJson) so I can use the following:

rio rasterize label.tif --like input_data_rs.tif < roads.geojson

I went through the https://github.com/developmentseed/skynet-data website but not quite sure how to use it for my data (input_data_rs.tif).

Answer (score 1):

If you

`docker run -v </path/to/output/dir>:/workdir/data -e MapboxAccessToken=<your token> -e QA_TILES=<name of country> developmentseed/skynet-data download-osm-tiles`

and then

`docker run -v </path/to/output/dir>:/workdir/data -e MapboxAccessToken=<your token> -e QA_TILES=<name of country> developmentseed/skynet-data download-osm-tiles`

then your MBTiles file will be rendered to PNGs in /path/to/output/dir/labels/color.